# Keep subarrays with a specific column value in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filtering

I have an array that looks kind of like this:

```
array(1) {
    ["Special"]=> array(4) {
        [0]=> array(2) { 
            ["ID"]=> int(1)
            ["Visitors"]=> int(2)
        }
        [1]=> array(2) {
            ["ID"]=> int(4)
            ["Visitors"]=> int(5)
        }
        [2]=> array(2) {
            ["ID"]=> int(169)
            ["Visitors"]=> int(0)
        }
    }
}
```

How can I filter it by 'ID' value, so the result would be looking like this (if I need to get arrays with ID = 4):

```
array(1) {
    ["Special"]=> array(4) {
        [1]=> array(2) {
            ["ID"]=> int(4)
            ["Visitors"]=> int(5)
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to use that function, but it doesn't return what I need:

```
function search($array, $key, $value) {
    $results = array();

    if (is_array($array)) {
        if (isset($array[$key]) && $array[$key] == $value) {
        
            $results[] = $array;
        }
        
        foreach ($array as $subarray) {
            $results = array_merge($results, search($subarray, $key, $value));
        }
    }

    return $results;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_filter` to do this:

```
$result = array(
    "Special" => array_filter($array["Special"], function($element) {
        return $element["ID"] == 4;
    })
);
```